# InDesign Applescript - Replacing missing fonts

Tags: replace, fonts, applescript, adobe-indesign

I have a missing font and I am trying to auto-replace it while doing other things, however I can't seem to ACTUALLY find it for whatever reason. After entering this code if I open the find/change window the find/change format windows look accurate,

[image]

[image]
but if I click them and change "Basic Character Formats" the family for both is reading as blank.

```
            tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"

            set find text preferences to nothing
            set change text preferences to nothing

            --Set the find options.     
            set properties of find change text options to {case sensitive:false, whole word:false, include footnotes:false, include hidden layers:false, include locked layers for find:false, include locked stories for find:false, include master pages:false}
            set properties of find text preferences to {applied font:"Avenier (T1)", font style:"55 Roman"}
            set properties of change text preferences to {applied font:"Avenier", font style:"Roman "}
            tell active document
                set myFoundItems to change text
                display dialog ("Found " & (count myFoundItems) & " instances.")
            end tell
        end tell
```

Does anyone have any clues how to fix this?

Comment: did you try a grep replacement?

Comment: Yes, here is the weird thing. I've tested it since this post with other fonts (installed random one, making a doc, deleting it) and it can find and replace them just fine.For whatever reason it's not finding Avenir (T1) even with the name and style copies directly from the events manager when I get the name of all missing fonts.